# слова исключения из запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется строка **слово1 ~~слово2 слово3 ~~слово4** , где **~~слово2** и **~~слово4** исключение из поиска запроса, нужно реализовать исключение из выдачи на базе запроса, приведенного ниже.
Наверное, LIKE не поддерживает исключения и для начала, нужно с помощью PHP получить массив из этих слов исключений и использовать NOT IN?

```
SELECT *
FROM   entries e 
       LEFT JOIN userdata u 
              ON u.user_id = e.user_id 
WHERE  Concat(Lower(subject), Lower(name), Lower(text), Lower(tags)) LIKE '%слово1 ~~слово2 слово3 ~~слово4%' 
       AND spam = 0 
ORDER  BY e.tid DESC, 
          e.time ASC 
LIMIT  0, 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формируем 2 строки через разделитель `|`: из входящих слов `(слово3|слово1)` и исключенных `(слово2|слово4)`.

Делаем запрос:

```
SELECT *
  FROM   entries e 
            LEFT JOIN userdata u 
              ON u.user_id = e.user_id 
 WHERE  NOT Concat(Lower(subject), Lower(name), Lower(text), Lower(tags))
            regexp '(слово2|слово4)'
        AND Concat(Lower(subject), Lower(name), Lower(text), Lower(tags))
            regexp '(слово1|слово3)'
       AND spam = 0 
ORDER  BY e.tid DESC, 
          e.time ASC 
LIMIT  0, 20
```

Можно конечно использовать NOT LIKE но он же ищет сразу целое вхождение, а него его части, так что придется на каждое слово отдельный писать

Answer (score 1):

Лучше исолльзовать для поиска sphinx, и не пилить велосипед...